# Stickers for non US residents?

Tags: discussion, stickers

> John says:
> August 28th, 2009 at 12:25 am
>
> Why do you not put a SASE question on meta and see how many votes it gets?

[Jeff now has the trilogy + How to Geek Stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/in-stickers-we-trust/). But, for now, he is planning on giving them just on SO DevDays!

Why, oh why, do you (Jeff) hate people from all over the world! :'( :'(

Should Jeff send Stickers to people that asks them? What should be the correct way to ask for stickers for those of us that live outside the US?

And one more thing, where are you from? (So Jeff sees wich countries are more demanding and can ban them)

**Update:** [Any users in the world can get free stickers -- just click here!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)

Comment: Oh the huge manatee is actually a pretty good game. Ive talked with the creator several times, he is quite nice.

Comment: Actually, it was a reference to this image ;) http://www.flickr.com/photos/ulrichp/1362599/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will eventually be solved with an [online store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/place-to-buy-stackoverflow-superuser-and-serverfault-merchandise-schwag), but keep in mind that it costs $0.96 for an airmail stamp. If you don't have access to US postage, when you ask for a stamp (even if by a self-address envelope), you're saying "hey, spend a dollar, plus the sticker cost, plus the time, just to get me a sticker."

Dan Dyer pointed out an IRC, but having a small stack of those sent from International readers of TDWTF, I can say it's well worth the $0.96 stamp to *not* have to go to the post office and try to get them to use it; no one uses those here in the states, and most postal workers don't see 'em.

Comment: Maybe a trade could be made? I send Jeff something from Argentina (a "mate" would be costly, but maybe something from the Patagonia) and he sends me the sticker.

Comment: *mate* is more like ma-tea. I'm not proposing sending a breeding mate.

Comment: Good thing you clarified that. I'm just saying: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Souvenir-Potpourri-Irish-Girl.aspx

Comment: Language is a tricky business...

Answer (score 6):

Canada! So close, but so far away.....

Comment: They made it to the Netherlands, so distance surely isn't the reason... :-P

Answer (score 4):

[International reply coupon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_reply_coupon)?

Can be [exchanged](http://www.royalmail.com/portal/rm/content1?catId=5200012&mediaId=27000662) for local postage.

Comment: The first time I received one of these, I thought it was just another sourvenir (it was mostly in another language, fine print in English); a reader pointed out that it was an IRC. No one at my local post office had ever seen one before.

Comment: @Alex - But in the end did they accept it?

Answer (score 4):

What about an exchange? If Jeff send me ServerFault stickers, the next time he goes to Peru I will invite him a couple of beers or pisco sour. Believe me, this is a fair deal.

Comment: Alcohol for *anything* is always a fair exchange. At least it seems that way after a few drinks.

Answer (score 2):

He should probably give them out to the people who show up at Dev Days first (I'm not going, so, no I'm not biased), then send the leftovers to anyone who sends him a SASE.

Edit: Based on the comments and other answers, I guess my "stupid American" is showing.  We can easily get mail delivered all over the world from our local post offices, so I was unaware that this was such a big issue in other parts of the world.  Sorry, I guess I have to recommend carrier pigeons?

Comment: Who would want the backing?

Comment: With the South African postal services it will take around 2 years from sending the SAS, if it does not go missing, get's stolen or hijacked somewhere along the way. Yes I know it's only and envolope with a sticker. You have no idea!

Comment: I agree. DevDays attendees should come first - I'm also not going :(

Comment: @Diago: We have the same problem in Germany. We call it *customs* :)

Comment: @Bill - Not your fault at all. Believe me you will be able to send it here.... It may just never arrive. I recieved Birthday cards from a friend in the UK, **4 Years** after they had been sent. Also the only international package that did arrive if not using couriers.

Comment: For the MSP (Microsoft Student Partner) program, whenever they want to give us a T-Shirt, stickers, or anything like that they have to manufacture them here (Argentina) because they can't pass them through customs

Comment: @Juan Manuel: I had no idea that MS did that. Clothing is heavely taxed, as well as almost everything. The only non taxed for international shippings is books, so Amazon is not completely useless/too expensive to even think about for us argentinians. :) Anyway, a sticker could be sent in a normal envelope as a letter.

Comment: "so I was unaware that this was such a big issue" — delivering mail isn't an issue, getting US stamps outside US (for SASE) is. Some other payment method would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I got my stickers fine.

Went through the normal procedure and [asked for them](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/), and they arrived in my mail all the way to the south lands (Argentina).

<sub>This was a long time ago, but I just found this question</sub>

Comment: Hunting for a Necromancer badge there? ;-) Btw, I also got my stickers fine. All the way to Belgium.

Comment: Not really @fre, I have quite a few. Fishing for the accepted answer is a better fit :)