# Place to buy StackOverflow, SuperUser and ServerFault Merchandise, Schwag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merchandise

I can't make it to DevDays. My locations (DC/NYC) sold out fast and my company has cut back on conference funding anyway. I still want some of the items mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/what-types-of-stack-overflow-schwag-would-you-like-to-see/14282#14282). Some customized for my user profile, some just generic logo and badge gear.

Please open a marketplace, storefront, what-have-you to sell some of these items once Dev Days are over. I think what you pull in should at least cover the costs *and* you get the benefit of folks walking into the office with their SO branded travel mug, etc.

Comment: @Jeff - status-completed  but where's the link?

Comment: may be just click the merchandise tag?

Comment: @Adam: You know where it is...

Answer (score 5):

For those people trying to find the store and are as puzzled as I was it is here:

http://store.stackexchange.com/

EDIT: The Stack Exchange store is now closed.

Comment: I've been told by the powers that be that this is not quite ready for prime time yet. Stay tuned for an official announcement.

Comment: @George - My apologies, I asked this in chat and thought I was one of the ignorant ones who always misses important things and finds out about them 3 days after they've already been announced. Let me know if you would like me to delete this answer?

Comment: Oh it's okay. Nothing I say is official - I'm just telling you what I heard.

Comment: `Unfortunately, due to operational logistics, we will no longer be selling Stack Exchange branded gear directly to our users. `
now where?

Comment: Not anymore. Why link is broken?

Comment: That's why you have Vistaprint ;)