# Don't you think that it's time for some Stack Exchange shirts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, swag

## <strike>[Success!!!](http://store.stackexchange.com/)</strike>

This is for you [Jeff](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/revolution).  We're asking and begging and pleading (and maybe even willing to pay) for some shirts!!!!  We know you've got to have some hiding <del>under your bed</del> on top of your PING PONG TABLE!

[image]

Don't you think it's time to share with those that deserve it?

Perhaps to the newly elected mods, or maybe even all those that ran as compensation for putting themselves out on the line and under the microscope?  Maybe for those that have been top users recently?  Or maybe you can make them available for the rest of us to purchase (at cost and shipping :P)?

And you know what, us Super User's aren't the only depraved souls in the Stack Exchange universe.  What about the [gamers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)? or the [Webbies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)? or the [Super Servers](https://serverfault.com/)? and the [mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/)? We want a T-Shirt revolution!  And we will not be silenced until we get one!

**I have a dream, where the Super User, the Stack Overflower, the Server Faulter, the Gamer, the Webber, and all equal SE site participant can have his/her own site T-Shirt!**

This week, was the second week I went eating waffles without a SE T-Shirt.  :(  How much longer will we suffer?

Comment: I just wish they made a webshop for Stack Exchange where we could buy some simple merchandise (like t-shirts) to promote the sites we love. In that regard @Popular Demand, I think it affects more sites than just SU

Comment: about time! we need a revolution for tshirts.

Comment: Hm, I seem to have effected change. Future 10kers and mods, please ignore my vote to close. (In fact; +1.)

Comment: @system - nice. I have two SF shirts, one black and one white, but that's quite a neat collection.

Comment: [Yes, this is me](http://i.imgur.com/2LZ67.jpg)

Comment: I never got my shirt for winning the contest for guessing the date of the millionth question on SO. Meh, +1 :)

Comment: Still no official response. :( I think we need a new tag: status-nobody-seems-to-care

Comment: @Ivo: That is an excellent idea.

Comment: @nhinkle, you're right, unfortunately. It's been "in the works" since at least [August of 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/place-to-buy-stackoverflow-superuser-and-serverfault-merchandise-schwag/18523#18523).

Comment: @Ivo yes it definately broader than the original trilogy. I'm devoted to the sites I actually use and contribute to, not so much to the platform which makes it possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Effectively completed at

## <s>http://shop.stackexchange.com</s>

> EDIT: the SE shop [has closed permanently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Note that we will be creating custom t-shirts and stickers for each community over time, in a "special edition while supplies last" sort of way.

<sub>hint: if you are a page 1 or page 2 user on a given Stack Exchange 2.0 site, you might get [something interesting](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) in your mailbox one day</sub>

Comment: let's go to shopping!

Comment: Ouch. Delivery prices are high if the destination address is outside of the US. To Germany, 18$ is the lowested fee possible. Followed by 32$ 67$ 71$ 147$. 147$ dollar? Overnight per Concorde?
Would it be possible to resell the SO hoodie from somewhere in europe?

Comment: I've made this comment elsewhere, but it's time to [outsource](http://www.cafepress.com/thingstore) the SE shop to cafepress (or similar).  You guys are sitting on a gold mine.  Jeff, this is the sort of fun, easy task that's well suited for a retiree like yourself  :-)

Answer (score 42):

I never even got the original, so my vote goes to

## Yes

Answer (score 27):

**yes**

**Ja(h)**

**Sí**

**כן**

**Да**

**Oui**

**हाँ**

**ಹೌದು**

**Kyllä**

**ஆம்**

**はい**

Just to prove a point, I'm adding my own answer on top of two upvotes.  I'm in for one too.

Comment: @Cristian What made you think it was Spanish? :P

Comment: LOL, I thought it could have been another language but I wish it was Spanish. That language was that?

Comment: Which one? I wrote the first six, then @Sathya added the next two. Then I added Finnish, courtesy of Google Translate.

Comment: Ja is correctly spelled Jah in German :)

Comment: Jah is correctly spelled Ja in Dutch.

Comment: Added a conditional h to Ja.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of just t-shirts for some of the top users and moderators, I'd rather enable **all users to buy a t-shirt!**

**Why?** The first time only the first 100 or so users of the Trilogy got a t-shirt, then there have been some other moments where they sent out small batches. But seriously? 100 t-shirts out of how many users?

By having some form of webshop, **anyone could buy a t-shirt!** <sub>and pay for the shipments all over the world...</sub>

[image: This brunch was made possible by SOIS, thanks Jeff!]

### Don't we want Stack Exchange users all over the world to enjoy their waffles in their favorite t-shirt?

Comment: Damn it, here in Italy we don't have waffles!

Comment: Fellow SU mod agrees http://i.imgur.com/2LZ67.jpg

Comment: I had my waffles this morning super user t-shirt-less... It was very cold and depressing :(

Comment: There was a web shop at one time.

Comment: I bought my shirts back then, and I don't think I was "the only one of 100 users"

Answer (score 13):

## Yes

**I'm currently wearing [a virtual T-shirt](http://www.jellymuffin.com/generators/tshirt/)...**

[image]

**But would love to wear a physical T-shirt instead, can you make my dream come true?**

<sub>FYI: The T-shirt seen in above picture is not available in physical format and is not the real Super User T-shirt but a fan-based off-spin.</sub>

Comment: I don't think anybody would recognize that as having to do anything with superuser.com - they'd just think you were a Linux nerd.

Comment: I should add the Windows colors in the heart, I'm a Windows Geek. ^^

Comment: @Aarobo : It is su in Linux -- there is no confusion.

Comment: @Hogan: they'd still be more likely to think of that than of superuser.com...

Answer (score 13):

## NO!

I believe it's time for **full blown Stack Exchange merchandise** and not just for a tshirt and a bunch of stickers

Some ideas found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/what-types-of-stack-overflow-schwag-would-you-like-to-see)

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add a black one to my collection (which exist of only 1 item right now).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Definitely promise to wear one to conferences :-)

Answer (score 3):

While [the Stack Exchange store no longer exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579/166017), the t-shirts themselves do! We still create site-specific swag when a site graduates, and send along a package to the top users. For generic Stack Exchange swag, there are a number of scenarios where we'll send along a t-shirt or stickers to say "thanks". You can't purchase them, but don't let that crush your dreams forever.

Comment: *"don't let that crush your dreams forever."* But it's ok to allow a little, limited time, dream crushing? Sounds reasonable.