# How about a Stack Exchange shirt?

Tags: feature-request, t-shirt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't you think that it's time for some Stack Exchange shirts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77556/dont-you-think-that-its-time-for-some-stack-exchange-shirts)

I already own SO and SU shirts, but given the recent explosion of SE sites, I think it would be very cool to print a Stack Exchange shirt. How about a tag cloud of all the different sites?

I would definitely buy this one.

Comment: @Yi - the store is a lie then? (only 11 days to go!!!)

Comment: Just curious, where did you got the Stack Overflow T-Shirt ?

Comment: @Myself - mine was hand-delivered by a unicorn along with a stack of stickers.

Comment: @Myself - I just followed the blog or Meta, and there was a link there (almost a year ago!). Now I can't seem to find it ... try asking a new question on Meta.

Comment: Dupe - [Don't you think that it's time for some Stack Exchange shirts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77556/dont-you-think-that-its-time-for-some-stack-exchange-shirts)

Comment: @Sathya - sorry, my bad. Although those shirts aren't tag clouds :(