# How to earn Stack Exchange swag or goodies?

Tags: support, swag

How can one earn Stack Exchange swag? For which sites is it applicable and is there any specific criterion for each site? If applicable what are the things one can get?

Comment: Mods sometimes get some goodies; however you should think twice of becoming mod just because of that: you'll have to earn that goodie many times over :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't, at least not for sure.

In the past, swag has been sent to top users of new beta sites as those sites graduate. If you look through the per-site metas of Travel, The Workplace, and Programmers you will find posts about it (probably a number of other sites too, but those are sites where I remember seeing the posts.) Of course, this does not mean that the same is going to happen for any current beta sites. See [How will graduation/election swag work with the changes to the "graduation" process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264222/how-will-graduation-election-swag-work-with-the-changes-to-the-graduation-proc) for a request - as yet unanswered - for precisely that information.

There once was a store, but there isn't now and no plans to revive it have been announced.

Shirts and mugs are sometimes given out as part of celebrations - however these are not pre-announced so you can't work your way towards earning them.

Comment: And I have it on good authority that some of those in charge have threatened to include spiders in the shipment. So I'm not sure if you really want swag any more.

Comment: @Kate Gregory Apparently they promised and there got to be a reason for the delay. Are they slowly making this swag thing obsolete.Even ignoring the questions regarding it?

Comment: @r2_d2 no. The graduation swag **uses the new design** so if you graduate without a new design, what goes on the swag? Nobody ever promised anything. I recommend you watch that question for updates. And I can tell that staff are not ignoring your question or the linked question (look at comments and edit histories.)

Comment: @Bart I hope spiders are not included in the new design ;-)

Comment: @r2_d2 But what if it's Halloween.SE?

Comment: I've posted an answer to the graduation question if y'all are interested in that.

Comment: @animuson What about reputation milestones swag like 100k?