# Can we have a "hats" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, winter-bash

I think that there should be a tag called "hats". It would be very useful for hat-related questions. Right now, there is a secret hats tag, but no hats tag. It would be helpful for questions about hats and maybe proposals for new hats.

I don't have 500 rep so I can't create this tag, but I think it should be added.

Comment: I think this is covered by the [tag:winter-bash] tag.

Comment: And [tag:hats] is actually synonymized to [tag:winter-bash] - we really don't need separate tags for the two of them given Winter Bash is just a period of earning hats.

Comment: @PolyGeo But what about questions about hats that are not in the winter bash?

Comment: Use the tag [tag:swag]

Answer (score 6):

Any talk of "Hats" on Meta is almost universally going to be about Winter Bash, so both [hat](/questions/tagged/hat) and [hats](/questions/tagged/hats) are already synonyms of [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash).

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/synonyms

Any physical items that Stack Exchange produces and sends out to users is known as [swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268878/307988), so the [swag](/questions/tagged/swag) tag should be sufficient to cover any questions about real-life Stack Exchange hats (such as the [strange diamond logo cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299484/307988) given to moderators).

Comment: You should probably mention that questions about specific hats should be tagged for the specific Winter Bash event.

Comment: Why is the mod hat "strange"?

Comment: @Catija [ask Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299484/307988)